# VFL with Xcode for Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have an existing application that has the positioning of all the elements written in code rather then in auto-layout. I am trying to use that existing code to add Auto-Layout for those elements.

I am trying to have the two buttons `xButton` and `checkButton` to show up at the bottom of the screen next to each other, which will work for all iPhone screens. The current behavior is that the buttons are offset towards the bottom of the screen.

Below is my code where my VFL is located - however this is placed in a UIView instead of a ViewController.

I have tried to figure this out on my own but no luck, I would love it if someone could give me a hand with this topic as well as this certain issue. 
Thank you

```
@implementation DraggableViewBackground{
    NSInteger cardsLoadedIndex; //%%% the index of the card you have loaded into the loadedCards array last
    NSMutableArray *loadedCards; //%%% the array of card loaded (change max_buffer_size to increase or decrease the number of cards this holds)

    UIButton* checkButton;
    UIButton* xButton;
}
//this makes it so only two cards are loaded at a time to
//avoid performance and memory costs
static const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2; //%%% max number of cards loaded at any given time, must be greater than 1
static const float CARD_HEIGHT = 386; //%%% height of the draggable card
static const float CARD_WIDTH = 290; //%%% width of the draggable card

@synthesize exampleCardLabels; //%%% all the labels I'm using as example data at the moment
@synthesize allCards;//%%% all the cards

- (void)loadView {
  [self setupView];
  exampleCardLabels = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Are you in the Technology Industry?",@"Do you have more then 3 years of work experiance?",@"Do you have more then 3 years of work experiance?",@"Are you willing to relocate?",@"Did you enjoy this app?", nil]; //%%% placeholder for card-specific information
  loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
  [self loadCards];

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setupView];
    exampleCardLabels = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Are you in the Technology Industry?",@"Do you have more then 3 years of work experiance?",@"Do you have more then 3 years of work experiance?",@"Are you willing to relocate?",@"Did you enjoy this app?", nil]; //%%% placeholder for card-specific information
    loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
    [self loadCards];
}
    return self;
}

//%%% sets up the extra buttons on the screen
// VFL Visual Formal Language -

- (void)setupView {

#warning customize all of this.  These are just place holders to make it look pretty
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.92 green:.93 blue:.95 alpha:1]; //the gray background colors

xButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)- 100, 59, 59)];
[xButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[xButton addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[xButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[xButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

checkButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)- 100, 59, 59)];
[checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[checkButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[checkButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

   [self addSubview:xButton];
   [self addSubview:checkButton];
}

#warning include own card customization here!
//%%% creates a card and returns it.  This should be customized to fit your needs.
// use "index" to indicate where the information should be pulled.  If this doesn't apply to you, feel free
// to get rid of it (eg: if you are building cards from data from the internet)

-(DraggableView *)createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
DraggableView *draggableView = [[DraggableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - CARD_WIDTH)/2,(self.frame.size.height - CARD_HEIGHT)/2, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT)];
draggableView.information.text = [exampleCardLabels objectAtIndex:index];//%%% placeholder for card-specific information
draggableView.delegate = self;
return draggableView;
}

//%%% loads all the cards and puts the first x in the "loaded cards" array
-(void)loadCards
{
if([exampleCardLabels count] > 0) {
    NSInteger numLoadedCardsCap =(([exampleCardLabels count] > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)?MAX_BUFFER_SIZE:[exampleCardLabels count]);
    //%%% if the buffer size is greater than the data size, there will be an array error, so this makes sure that doesn't happen

    //%%% loops through the exampleCardsLabels array to create a card for each label.  This should be customized by removing "exampleCardLabels" with your own array of data
    for (int i = 0; i<[exampleCardLabels count]; i++) {
        DraggableView* newCard = [self createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:i];
        [allCards addObject:newCard];

        if (i<numLoadedCardsCap) {
            //%%% adds a small number of cards to be loaded
            [loadedCards addObject:newCard];
        }
    }

    //%%% displays the small number of loaded cards dictated by MAX_BUFFER_SIZE so that not all the cards
    // are showing at once and clogging a ton of data
    for (int i = 0; i<[loadedCards count]; i++) {
        if (i>0) {
            [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:i] belowSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:i-1]];
        } else {
            [self addSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        cardsLoadedIndex++; //%%% we loaded a card into loaded cards, so we have to increment
    }
}
}

#warning include own action here!
//%%% action called when the card goes to the left.
// This should be customized with your own action
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
{
//do whatever you want with the card that was swiped
//    DraggableView *c = (DraggableView *)card;

[loadedCards removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //%%% card was swiped, so it's no longer a "loaded card"

if (cardsLoadedIndex < [allCards count]) { //%%% if we haven't reached the end of all cards, put another into the loaded cards
    [loadedCards addObject:[allCards objectAtIndex:cardsLoadedIndex]];
    cardsLoadedIndex++;//%%% loaded a card, so have to increment count
    [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1)] belowSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-2)]];
}
}

#warning include own action here!
//%%% action called when the card goes to the right.
// This should be customized with your own action
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card
{
//do whatever you want with the card that was swiped
//    DraggableView *c = (DraggableView *)card;

[loadedCards removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //%%% card was swiped, so it's no longer a "loaded card"

if (cardsLoadedIndex < [allCards count]) { //%%% if we haven't reached the end of all cards, put another into the loaded cards
    [loadedCards addObject:[allCards objectAtIndex:cardsLoadedIndex]];
    cardsLoadedIndex++;//%%% loaded a card, so have to increment count
    [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1)] belowSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-2)]];
}

}

//%%% when you hit the right button, this is called and substitutes the swipe
-(void)swipeRight
{
DraggableView *dragView = [loadedCards firstObject];
dragView.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeRight;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1;
}];
[dragView rightClickAction];
}

//%%% when you hit the left button, this is called and substitutes the swipe
-(void)swipeLeft
{
DraggableView *dragView = [loadedCards firstObject];
dragView.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeLeft;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1;
}];
[dragView leftClickAction];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: But what's the question? You explain neither what you want to do nor what actually happens.

Comment: I apologize @matt, I am trying to have the two buttons `xButton` and `checkButton` to show up at the bottom of the screen next to each other, which will work for all iPhone screens. The current behavior is that it is offset on the towards the bottom of the screen and once the device screen is switched to iPhone 4 the buttons are no longer visible.

Comment: I don't see any VFL in the code you posted.

Comment: @joern, I am trying to add VFL to help with the layout of the existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do with the buttons you can use VFL like this:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"button1": button1, @"button2": button2};
NSArray *horizontalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button1(150)][button2(150)]-|"
                                                                            options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:viewsDict];
NSArray *verticalConstraintsButton1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button1]-20-|"
                                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:viewsDict];
NSArray *verticalConstraintsButton2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button2]-20-|"
                                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:viewsDict];
[self.view addConstraints:horizontalContraints];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraintsButton1];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraintsButton2];
```

This give the buttons each a width of 150 pt and places them 20 pt from the left, right and bottom of your view.